# Loop on Unix, basic calculator of geometric figures

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix

I am trying to create a calculator of geometric figures and I am stuck with a loop. I am using menu in a shell script and so far no luck.

Can please someone help me with that?

The current script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Welcome, please enter username:"

read $username

echo "WELCOME  $( getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1), This is a basic calculator of square,circle and rectangle. "


echo  "Please choose from 1,2 or 3 to continue: " 

echo "1. Rectangle"
echo "2. Circle"
echo "3. Square"
echo "4. Quit"

read choice

if [ $choice -eq 1 ]
then
echo "You choose rectangle"
echo "Enter the height:"
read height
echo "Enter the width:"
read width
area=`echo "$height * $width"|bc`
echo "The area of the rectangle is:"$area

else
if [ $choice -eq 2 ]
then
echo "You choose circle"
echo "Enter the radius of the circle:"
read radius
area1=`echo "3.141 * $radius * $radius"|bc`
echo "The area of the circle is:"$area1

else
if [ $choice -eq 3 ]
then
echo "You choose square"
echo "Enter the width of the square:"
read w
area2=`echo "$w * $w"|bc`
echo "The area of the circle is:"$area2

else
If [ $choice -eq 4 ]
then "You choose quit"

"Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
```

As you can see, I have no idea how to stop the loop and "quit".

Thanks!

Comment: Formatting your question would make it easier to understand it and reply to it. You can start by typing 4 spaces before each line of code ...

Comment: @rainer Or just click the `{}` button instead of typing spaces manually.

Comment: What loop are you talking about? I don't see a loop in your code.

Comment: If I choose any option netween1 2 3 I can do the geometric calculation. From there I can't quit the calculation.
I need to add quit option and a way to select another option.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Welcome, please enter username:"

read $username

echo "WELCOME  $( getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1), This is a basic calculator of square,circle and rectangle. "

while true
do
echo  "Please choose from 1,2 or 3 to continue: " 

echo "1. Rectangle"
echo "2. Circle"
echo "3. Square"
echo "4. Quit"

read choice

if [ $choice -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "You choose rectangle"
    echo "Enter the height:"
    read height
    echo "Enter the width:"
    read width
    area=`echo "$height * $width"|bc`
    echo "The area of the rectangle is:"$area

elif [ $choice -eq 2 ]
then
    echo "You choose circle"
    echo "Enter the radius of the circle:"
    read radius
    area1=`echo "3.141 * $radius * $radius"|bc`
    echo "The area of the circle is:"$area1

elif [ $choice -eq 3 ]
then
    echo "You choose square"
    echo "Enter the width of the square:"
    read w
    area2=`echo "$w * $w"|bc`
    echo "The area of the circle is:"$area2

elif [ $choice -eq 4 ]
then 
    break
else 
    echo "invalid option"
fi
done
```

I think you want to do this. This will loop infinitely until you press 4.

Comment: Yep, that is what I wanted to do! Thanks!